# EF core: "Invalid object name [TableName]" error even though the table exists in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

So I am building a very simple MVC web application for a coding test and I am using EF core to store two tables.

I started setting up the first table, "SalesPerson" and got it to work, and now I have added the second table "Orderline". The problem is now, that when running I get this invalid object error like the table "Orderline" does not exist in the database.

I have tried to search on stack overflow on this issue, but it seems that only people who have discrepancies between the names in the cs class and in the database, but I'm fairly sure that I have not, because Visual Studio is giving me a compile-error if I use another, but similar name saying that it is not in the database.

I have built it exactly the same way as I built the first class/table and I am operating on it the same way as well.

I get the error in the DbInitializer when calling:

```
if (context.Orderline.Any())
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("TRUNCATE TABLE Orderline");
}
```

It is the context.Orderline.Any() that says that the object does not exist.

Comment: You are  looking at the correct database that really contains that table?

Comment: Either as the above person said you may have created it in a different DB (or maybe even different server if you have different environments).  Or possibility is you did not setup permissions correctly for it and the ID you are using to connect does not have permissions.

Comment: Hmmm, it is a simple beginner environment, so I’m pretty sure that it is the same database. Both tables are in the same Context at least if that counts?

Comment: Which SQL database you use? Did you added entity-framework migrations and updated Database after creation of second table?